# create installer using command line

Tags: deployment, command-line, installation, windows-installer

I am writing a script that pulls files from my development folders and would like to generate an installer with those files.
I would like to if there is a way to create MSI installers using command line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. The very flexible Windows Installer XML Toolset. A pretty good tutorial on how to use it is this [link](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial)

The toolset is [here](http://wix.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define "create".   If you mean "build" or "compile" then yes, pretty much every MSI authoring tool out there supports some form of automated build ... usually even MSBuild support.

If you mean "author" and "build" it's technically possible but not usually advised.  Installation is too complicated to be auto magically developed.